# Filter numbers from one table from another

Tags: excel, excel-formula

im interested in learn more about excel, and i thought "is it possible for me to sort a table as in the example?".
For example the number "1" in the "Posição" table is the highest number in the "Saída"(41) table and so on, I'm trying to understand if I have to filter or if a condition is needed...

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish and what have you tried? And it is suggested to paste a TEXTUAL Data instead of image, so that some trying to help may easily copy from the post

Comment: I see in "Posição" is a RANK formula. What exactly do you need to filter? What condition? Or do want to sort?